# UnitTest -NullException issue when mock

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm trying to do a mock setup in a [TestInitialize] and put in a list as my mock object.

Why am I getting a System.NullReferenceException below. What am I doing wrong?
I'm using moq and ninject.

```
[TestClass]
public class RepoTests
{
    private Mock<ISellBuyPipeLineRepo> _mock;
    private List<Product> _products;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Init()
    {
        _products = new List<Product>()
        {
            new Product(){ProductId = 1, StockQuantity = 10 },
            new Product(){ProductId = 2, StockQuantity = 20 }
        };

        _mock = new Mock<ISellBuyPipeLineRepo>();

        _mock.Setup(o => o.Products).Returns(_products); 
    }

}
```

Comment: `_mock` is never initialized.

Comment: It' works. I will close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have to initialize the variable `_mock` before using it:

```
this.__mock = new Mock<ISellBuyPipeLineRepo>();
```

See [Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) for an overview.